# Referencing TFS 2008 assemblies on a computer without a TFS installation

Tags: git

I'm writing a hook for Git that will let me select workitems from TFS 2008 and inject them into the commit message from Git.

I've already written a stub so that I can develop my functionality without referencing TFS 2008. However, when creating the real thing, how do I get a copy of the desired Team Foundation assemblies on my local computer?

1. I don't want to install TFS 2008 because this is overkill (besides, I like my projects to build in a continuous integration cycle. Bit hard to install TFS on a buildcomputer ;-)
2. There is a TFS 2005 SDK which installs a copy of the assemblies. However, this is only for 2005. There is no SDK for TFS 2008 yet ([see following post van Brian Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2008/01/09/tfs-sdk.aspx)).

The only option I see is manually copying the assemblies from a TFS 2008  instance and trying to reference them.

Is there an alternative that I'm simply not seeing?

Thanks for the webservices answer, but the TFS webservices are undocumented and Microsoft is recommending to use the .NET API instead of the webservices. The API is supposed to be stable - the webservices are liable to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Install the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=30402623-93ca-479a-867c-04dc45164f5b&displaylang=en). You will find the assemblies in Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You could talk to TFS via web services, that would remove the need for the TFS assemblies.

Comment: Except for the fact webservices are undocumented and Microsoft itself is saying that you shouldn't use them directly...